# Switch the Fn and Ctrl keys on a Sony VAIO

Tags: sony-vaio

I just got a Sony VAIO (Fit 13). All my current and previous laptops have Fn key that's to the left of Ctrl key. I remember seeing a Sony utility on a VAIO Z that allows you to switch the Fn and the Ctrl key, but I couldn't find it anymore. I've also tried SharpKey but it doesn't recognize the Fn key. Is there a way to switch these two keys on a Sony VAIO?

Comment: I think my case is similar (that a 3rd party app will not work), so I'm looking for an utility released by Sony.

Comment: This might be an option in the BIOS settings? You can access the BIOS settings by pressing either F2, ESC, or maybe another F-key just a second after turning on your computer. Just be very careful not to modify _any_ other setting.

Comment: AFAIK There is no such utility, especially not publically available.  You'll have to ask Sony for it, but again, I doubt it exists.  Usually the "FN" key switcher settings are for toggling whether you need to hit FN or not to use the extra F key functions.